# How to find the number of rows between a logical TRUE value in one column and the closest previous TRUE value in another column in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series of daily observations, What I need to do is:

1. find the observations that exceed a prespecified value (A). For example, these are 50 values in my dataset of 365 rows (days)
2. For each of the observations identified in step 1, I need to find the closest previous (i) and later values (j) which exceed other prespecified values (B and C) & obtain the number of rows between  i and j.

I am quite new to R and trying to write a function that does step 2.

Thanks in advance!

Initial data:

```
> head(dta)
        Date      Temp
1 2045-01-01  2.666667
2 2045-01-02  5.095833
3 2045-01-03  7.445833
4 2045-01-04 12.050000
5 2045-01-05 15.162500
6 2045-01-06  7.716667
```

For the 1st step, I have created logical columns which identify the values meeting the A, B & C conditions.

```
> head(dta)
        Date      Temp     A     B     C
1 2045-01-01  2.666667 FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 2045-01-02  5.095833 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
3 2045-01-03  7.445833  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
4 2045-01-04 12.050000  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
5 2045-01-05 15.162500  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
6 2045-01-06  7.716667  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

What I ideally need is to identify the index of each TRUE in column A, go back from there to find the closest TRUE in column B and go ahead to find the closest TRUE in column C. For the data shown above, first TRUE in column A is at position 3, closest TRUE going backwards in column B is at position 2, and the next TRUE in column C is at position 5. The output that I need is 5-2 = 3. This needs to be repeated for each of the TRUE values in column A.

Something like the match function in R should be ideal, but how do I initiate R at each of the TRUE values in column A instead of the beginning of the dataset.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you consider making a composite column that `paste()`s the two columns and the searching for what are probably tens of earlier questions about how to handle sequences in single columns? The usual strategy for single columns is `cumsum` on a logical test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the closest entry based on some inequality (here: one date smaller/greater than another) you can used so-called rolling joins:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Date,      ~Temp,
  "2045-01-01",  2.666667,
  "2045-01-02",  5.095833,
  "2045-01-03",  7.445833,
  "2045-01-04", 12.050000,
  "2045-01-05", 15.162500,
  "2045-01-06",  7.716667
)

# convert dates and add index
df <- df |> mutate(
  id = row_number(),
  Date = ymd(Date)
)

# subset dataframe according to conditions
A <- df |> filter(Temp > 6)
B <- df |> filter(Temp > 3)
C <- df |> filter(Temp > 15)

# merge via rolling join
merged <- A |> 
  left_join(B, join_by(closest(Date > Date))) |> 
  left_join(C, join_by(closest(Date.x < Date)))

# clean up results
merged |> 
  select(
    Date = Date.x,
    Temp = Temp.x,
    id_B = id.y,
    id_C = id
  ) |> 
  mutate(difference = id_C - id_B)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   Date        Temp  id_B  id_C difference
#>   <date>     <dbl> <int> <int>      <int>
#> 1 2045-01-03  7.45     2     5          3
#> 2 2045-01-04 12.0      3     5          2
#> 3 2045-01-05 15.2      4    NA         NA
#> 4 2045-01-06  7.72     5    NA         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I'm assuming that what you describe as the "closest" date cannot be the same date here.